# Why is my gmail login not working through firebase

Tags: firebase-authentication, gmail, google-signin

I don't know anything about coding and have been learning as I go along

i cant seem to log in via google even though I do show up as active on firebase

can anyone see if I'm missing something?

```
//Relate to google login
   private void handleSignInResult(Task<GoogleSignInAccount> completedTask) {
       try {
           GoogleSignInAccount account = completedTask.getResult(ApiException.class);
           if (account != null) {
               String id = account.getId();
               String fname = "" + account.getGivenName();
               String lname = "" + account.getFamilyName();

               // if we do not get the picture of user then we will use default profile picture

               String pic_url;
               if (account.getPhotoUrl() != null) {
                   pic_url = account.getPhotoUrl().toString();
               } else {
                   pic_url = "null";
               }


               if (fname.equals("") || fname.equals("null"))
                   fname = getResources().getString(R.string.app_name);

               if (lname.equals("") || lname.equals("null"))
                   lname = "User";

               Change_Url_to_base64(id, fname, lname, pic_url, "gmail");


           }
       } catch (ApiException e) {
           Log.w("Error message", "signInResult:failed code=" + e.getStatusCode());
       }

   }


   public void Change_Url_to_base64(final String user_id,
                                    final String f_name, final String l_name, String picture, final String singnup_type) {

       Functions.show_loader(this, false, true);
       Log.d(Variables.tag, picture);

       if (picture.equalsIgnoreCase("null")) {
           Call_Api_For_Signup(user_id, f_name, l_name, picture, singnup_type);
       } else {
           Glide.with(this)
                   .asBitmap()
                   .load(picture)
                   .into(new CustomTarget<Bitmap>() {
                       @Override
                       public void onResourceReady(@NonNull Bitmap resource, @Nullable Transition<? super Bitmap> transition) {
                           String image_base64 = Functions.bitmap_to_base64(Login_A.this, resource);
                           Call_Api_For_Signup(user_id, f_name, l_name, image_base64, singnup_type);
                       }

                       @Override
                       public void onLoadCleared(@Nullable Drawable placeholder) {
                       }
                   });
       }
   }
```

I'm only righting this part because the website keeps telling me that its mostly code and i need to add more details even though i dont know what else to ask or add

Comment: im not sure i understand the question, log in through google where? how?  you might want to read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I'm trying to log into an app I created as a user to test the app. I'm trying my Gmail log in but it doesn't seem to be working